# koha user rules and cataloging (Koha Library Management System)

Tags: marc

Is there a plugin for koha that allows you to make the following points? or is possible to do this configurations on koha?

1. Blocking and unblocking of records, by users of the headquarters library with system administration level, through validation of bibliographic records.
2. A bibliographic record, after being validated and approved, at the head office, can be blocked by the head office administrator who will have superior permissions; this permission will also allow you to unlock the record.
3. The blocking system must inhibit the edition of the bibliographic record and its elimination by the other libraries, as well as the elimination of copies, but copies may be added.
4. If a bibliographic record is not validated by the head office library, it can only be deleted and edited by the library that created it and by the head office library, if it does not have other associated copies from other libraries

Comment: What is wrong about this question to be closed? i don't understand that....

Comment: I believe it is considered off-topic because it asks for software recommendations.